# 'C-s C-w' does not work - Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, cygwin

`C-s C-w` : Saves the file with a different name. Asks you for the name.

I read this point from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujODL7MD04Q

But when I type `C-s C-w`, I see that below screen, not asking any name,

### [image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I definitely recommend you work through the in-built tutorial. Type `C-h t` to begin. It takes a while, but it remembers how far through you are, so you can do it in chunks. It will really help to get you up and running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default sequence is <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd>

If you read C-s C-w somewhere, report the error to the author.